# Python error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '<....>'

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
import tweepy
from tweet import TweetBuilder
from libs.session import Session

class GameHandler:

    open_sessions = []


    def get_session(self, sessionname):
        for session in GameHandler.open_sessions:
            #FOLLOWING STATEMENT GOES WRONG
            if session.roomname == sessionname:
                return session
        return None

    def session_create(self, sessionname, owner_id, owner_name):
        new = Session(sessionname, owner_id, owner_name).add_player(owner_id, owner_name)
        GameHandler.open_sessions.append(new)
        return TweetBuilder.new_session(sessionname, owner_name)

    def session_join(self, sessionname, player_id, player_name):
        session = self.get_session(sessionname)
        if session != None:
            session.add_player(player_id, player_name)
            return TweetBuilder.join_session(session, player_name)
        return ""
```

Also part of the Session class:

```
class Session:

    def __init__(self, name, owner_id, owner_name):
         #keep track of tweets
         self.tweetid_start = None
         self.tweetid_current = None

         #game elements
         self.roomname = name
         #THIS LINE WORKS CORRECTLY
         print(self.roomname)
         self.players = []
         self.currentround = None
         self.roundnumber = 0        
         self.players.append(Player(owner_id, owner_name))
```

When I call `session_create()` everything works fine. The app runs `Session.__init__()`, the print statement prints `self.roomname`.

When I call `session_join()`, and `session_join()` calls `get_session()` problems arise. The for loop is supposed to iterate over the Session-array called `open_sessions`, but the moment it tries to access the Session-attribute called 'roomname' it gives me the following error:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roomname'`

Why are my Session-objects suddenly NoneType?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the complete error trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    new = Session(sessionname, owner_id, owner_name).add_player(owner_id, owner_name)
    GameHandler.open_sessions.append(new)
```

By immediately calling `add_player` on the newly created `Session`, `new` is *not* the `Session` but the result of `add_player`, and whatever that does, it seems to return `None`. Thus you are adding a bunch of `None` objects to your `open_sessions` list. Use this instead:

```
    new = Session(sessionname, owner_id, owner_name)
    new.add_player(owner_id, owner_name)
    GameHandler.open_sessions.append(new)
```

Or if you want to keep it the way it was, you could change your `Session` class to provide kind of a ["fluent interface"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and have `add_player` (and other methods) `return self`:

```
class Session:
    ...
    def add_player(self, id_, name):
        ....
        return self
```